# Plot a grouped by data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, indexing, pandas-groupby

I have this data frame I want to plot. I has more country, years, and variables. I am just pasting a part of it as an example.

```
                       gdp_share    military_exp
year    Country                     
2010    USA            5.0  768465792.0
        China          2.0  138028416.0 
        Korea          3.0  31117330.0  
        Russia         4.0  43120560.0  
2011    USA            5.0  758988352.0
        China          2.0  149022400.0
        Korea          3.0  31543720.0
        Russia         3.0  46022120.0
```

I've used `data = data.set_index(["year", "Country"])` to index it by year and Country.

I've also tried:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(data.year.unique())
data.groupby(["year", "Country"]).mean()['gdp_share'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
```

But that didn't work. It keeps throwing this error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'`

Is there a way of plotting a line chart with lines for each country for each year that only show the `gdp_share` column in the y axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.unstack('Country')['gdp_share'].plot()
```

Output:

[image]